# AWS Cognito Post Authentication Lambda Trigger - groupConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is it possible, via a post-authentication lambda to alter the list of groups exposed by the AWS Cognito Identity token?

The documentation for the post-authenticaion Lambda states the following:

"....
groupConfiguration structure – contains group-related information that can override group-related claims in the identity token."

Full docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-auth

The AWS Cognito Identity token exposes the current payload:

```
{
  sub: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  cognito:groups: [
    "group1",
    "group2"
  ],
  iss: "https://cognito-idp.*****/**-****-1_********",
  cognito:username: "Google_*****************",
  .....
}
```

What I would like to to, via a post-authentication lambda is to alter the list of cognito-groups. 
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mixup in the documentation. This is not currently supported. We are actively working to fix it.

Comment: Sad to hear that this is not currently supported. Do you have an estimate on when this feature will be available?

Comment: I cannot comment on this, but this feature is definitely on our current roadmap.